# Change displacement in C# with keyboard?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to change the displacement of a gameObject with a keyboard press in C# for unity? I tried using this, but nothing happens:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
   platform[i, j].transform.position = 
       new Vector3(platform[i, j].transform.position.x, 
                   y *= y,
                   platform[i, j].transform.position.z);
```

Comment: You may want to explain in your question what you mean by *"displacement of a gameObject"*.

Comment: You should do this in Update method. Why y*=y ? it's seems to take quickly a very high value !

Comment: it should be y += 1, not y *= y.

Answer (score 0):

well your code seems okay but, if your 'y' is 1 or 0, then y *= y will not be able to move your gameObject alone the Y-axis.

Comment: so should i increment it to y+=1 like what Leo Bartkus said above?

Comment: @riviera990 y+=1 will be fine, if these code is inside your update()

Answer (score 0):

Use the Translate method on your transform:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    platform[i, j].transform.Translate(0,1,0);
```

This sample will move the object upwards very fast. You can use `platform[i, j].transform.forward` as the vector if you want forward movement.

See the docs on [Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). Note the `relativeTo` parameter as well. Useful for local vs world space movement. Also take note of the usage of deltaTime in the samples.

Also take note of @csblo's comment to put this code in the `Update()` method.